# Difference between two dateTime in hh:MM format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two datetime fields. Now I want to get difference between two date in hh:MM format.

I have use below code but it does not work.

```
       DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);          
        TimeSpan duration = dt1 - dt;
        string str = duration.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

I want to get out put for above code : 24:00. 
But Above code's out put is : 1.00:00:00.2187588

So how to convert this value in hh:MM format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, is that when you subtract, the hour and minute component stay the same, however, the difference in days is 1. So you use the time difference in ticks and you construct your time accordingly.
Try this:

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        TimeSpan duration = dt1 - dt;
        long durationTicks = Math.Abs(duration.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
        long hours = durationTicks / ( 1000 * 60 * 60);
        long minutes = (durationTicks - (hours * 60 * 60 *1000 )) / (1000 * 60);

        System.Console.WriteLine(hours.ToString("00") + ":" + minutes.ToString("00"));
```

Yields:

```
        24:00
```

Comment: Hi Thanks but I dont want negative difference. So how can I avoid negative difference?

Comment: @Hitesh: Taking the absolute value of the `durationTicks` should work for you.